# Rails - query database and don't show errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `Notifications` table that a query using an ID provided by the url parameters hash.

Say I have the following URL : `videos/11?notification=5`

The `5` maps to a notification. But say a user change `5`for `7`and submits the URL. If a notification with ID 7 does not exist, Rails sends an error saying it `could not find a notification with ID 7`. I would like it to simply ignore the error and continue. I am making some tests after the find so nothing unwanted happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller, you are likely using `Notification.find`. This will throw an error if no record can be found with the given id. The finder method `Notification.find_by_id` will not throw an exception if no record can be found, and will instead return `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this :

```
Notification.find_by_id 7
```

It will return nil if there is no records with id 7.